# .xcworkspace wasn't found after pod install with no error message

Tags: cocoapods

I am a newbie in cocoapods and I would be appreciated if you help.
Today I want to use cocoapods to manager my dependencies in my project.
So my Profile is:

```
platform :ios, '8.0' 

target 'TargetName' do  
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

But after running `pod install`, I got the message as follow:
[pod install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssMLh.jpg)

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Generating Pods project
[1]    53417 abort      pod install
```

After that, I can't find the TargetName.xcworkspace and the Podfile.lock but the Pods folder is there.
That's weird because there are no more error messages here.

I installed the cocoapods exactly according to the official guides. And here are the environments:

1. pod: 1.1.1
2. ruby: 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]
3. gem: 2.6.8
4. Xcode: 8.2.1

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I upgrade cocoapods(now Version 1.2.0.beta.1) and solve my problem.